# Cargar vista de Laravel con Ajax

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, ajax

Me interesa cargar una vista de otra ruta con ajax, para cargar el html sin recargar la página.
El problema que tengo es que me hace la petición ajax, pero me vuelve atras y no me pinta el HTML.

Como se puede ver, al dar siguiente me hace lña peticion, me devuelve el html que me interesa obtener, pero al aceptar el alert me lo pinta, pero automaticamente me vuelve atras y me lo borra.

No encuentro el problema, porque no redirijo en ningun momento hacia la vista anterior. La url a la que hago la petición, ejecuta la funcion store, que me devuelve la vista, se puede ver en el console log que me devuelve todo el html.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

HTML:

```
 @extends('template.app')
    
    @section('content')
    
    <div class="container text-center opciones">
        <div class="row text-center">
            <div class="col contenido">
                <h6 class="titulo">Qué necesitas?</h6>
                <form method="POST">
                    {{method_field('GET')}}
                    {{ csrf_field() }}
                    <input type="checkbox" name="servicio0" value="Web corporativa">Web corporativa</br>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="servicio1" value="Web catálogo">Web catálogo</br>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="servicio2" value="Tienda online">Tienda online</br>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="servicio3" value="Web con motor de reservas">Web con motor de reservas</br>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="servicio4" value="Web restaurante + delivery">Web restaurante + delivery</br>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="servicio5" value="Alojamiento web y/o dominios">Alojamiento web y/o dominios</br>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="servicio6" value="Otros">Otros</br>
    
                    <h6 class="inputform">Como te llamas?</h6>
                    <input class="input" type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" placeholder="Introduce tu nombre">
    
                    <button type="submit" class="btnsiguiente">Siguiente</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    @endsection
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $('.btnsiguiente').click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type:'GET',
            url: '/paso2',
            success: function(respuesta){
                console.log(respuesta);
                alert('SUCCESS');
                $('.contenido').html(respuesta);
            },
            error: function (){
                console.log('Error');
            }
        })
    })
})
```

LARAVEL:

```
public function store(Request $request){
        
        $info["nombre"] = $request->input('nombre');
        if ($request->has('servicio0')) {
            $info["servicios"][] = $request->input('servicio0');
        }
        if ($request->has('servicio1')) {
            $info["servicios"][] = $request->input('servicio1');
        }
        if ($request->has('servicio2')) {
            $info["servicios"][] = $request->input('servicio2');
        }
        if ($request->has('servicio3')) {
            $info["servicios"][] = $request->input('servicio3');
        }
        if ($request->has('servicio4')) {
            $info["servicios"][] = $request->input('servicio4');
        }
        if ($request->has('servicio5')) {
            $info["servicios"][] = $request->input('servicio5');
        }
        if ($request->has('servicio6')) {
            $info["servicios"][] = $request->input('servicio6');
        }

        
        return View::make('pas2')->render();

        /*$peticion = new Petition;
        $peticion->nombre = $info["nombre"];
        $servicio = implode(', ', $info["servicios"]);

        $peticion->servicio = $servicio;        
        $peticion->save();*/
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que estas usando un `button-submit`, por lo cual siempre hara una peticion en tu propia pagina(por eso te vuelve atras)

Para solucionarlo tienes que cancelar ese evento(submit) para que no te pase lo anterior dicho, utilizando simplemente:

```
event.preventDefault();
```

Esto basicamente significa que(segun documentacion):

> Cancela el evento si este es cancelable, sin detener el resto del funcionamiento del evento, es decir, puede ser llamado de nuevo

En tu codigo seria solo agregar eso

```
$('.btnsiguiente').click(function () {
    //Cancelamos el evento submit
    event.preventDefault();
    //Hacemos la peticion
    $.ajax({
        type:'GET',
        url: '/paso2',
        success: function(respuesta){
            console.log(respuesta);
            alert('SUCCESS');
            $('.contenido').html(respuesta);
        },
        error: function (){
            console.log('Error');
        }
    })
})
```

**Referencia**

- https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault